# How can I use Java to programmaticaly convert an Internal Stylesheet of a web-page to an inline one?

Tags: java, css

Is there a ready-made tool or utility that does that already

Comment: what is an internal stylesheet?

Comment: An internal style sheet is a section on an HTML page that contains style definitions. Internal style sheets are defined by using the <style> tag within the <head> area of the document. Here is an example of an internal style sheet:

<html>
<head>
 <title>Internal Style Sheet Example</title>
 <style>
  <!--
    body { background: #C9F1C5 }
    h1 { color: #54B24B; font: bold 14px Verdana, Arial, Helvetica }
    p { font: 12px Verdana, Arial, Helvetica }
  -->
 </style> 
</head>
.....

Comment: possible duplicate of [Automatically convert Style Sheets to inline style](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4521557/automatically-convert-style-sheets-to-inline-style)

Answer (score 1):

You could just open the **CSS** file and just embed its content into a *style* tag.

It should not be that hard:

```
FileReader frCSS = new FileReader("your_css.css");
FileReader frHTML = new FileReader("your_html.html");
FileWriter output = new FileWriter("result.html");
```

Then parse *frHTML* and copy its content to *output* until you find the *head* opening tag. When you do, open a *style* tag and copy all contents from *frCSS*. Then, close the *style* tag and copy the remaining portion of *frHTML*.

It's not pretty, but it can be done.

Comment: That would convert an External Stylesheet to Internal.
I am interested in converting internal to inline, if possible, without the heavylifting of doing all the parsing myself...