# How do I send an XSL formatted XML file as the message of a JavaMail e-mail

Tags: html, xml, xslt, jakarta-mail, sendmessage

I am using JavaMail to send an e-mail.  My goal is to send the contents of an xml file formatted by an xsl file as the message of the e-mail.  Is this possible?

I know that the following code can be used to send a string containing html.

```
message.set.Content(htmlString, "text/html");
```

Am I correct in my assumption that the formatting information to create a html message in an e-mail must be embedded in the html and that there is no way to connect to a css?
If this is so, then the same must apply to xml and xsl.
If there is a way to join an existing xml file and an existing xsl file in the body of a JavaMail e-mail, I would be very grateful to anyone who can give me the code that makes this possible.

If it is impossible, I will be happy to be informed of this and pointed in the right direction.  I suspect that I will need to parse the xml file and convert it to a string containing html formatting.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It's true that most email clients will not process CSS. [Here's a chart](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/).

As a result, it's commonplace to apply formatting by transforming the CSS-formatted HTML to an inline-style that most email clients can handle. Sometimes this is done by preprocessing the document with XSLT.

If you want to take this route, I suggest you look at the [Saxon XSLT processor](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/saxon6.5.3/api-guide.html) to preprocess your XML document.

Another option to handle this problem would be something like [Emogrifier](http://www.pelagodesign.com/sidecar/emogrifier/), [Premailer](https://github.com/alexdunae/premailer), or even this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4521557/automatically-convert-style-sheets-to-inline-style). Which processes a CSS and HTML into one inline-styled email-safe document.