# Inline external CSS with HTML

Tags: java, html, css, parsing, jstyleparser

I am looking for a java library which can inline an external `CSS` file with a `HTML` document based on its ID/class attributes.

I've found [**jStyleParser**](http://cssbox.sourceforge.net/jstyleparser/index.php) but I am not sure if this is the right library for me. I seem to fail to understand if it can do the job of inlining the `CSS` on the elements from the HTML. The documentation and examples is not what I expected.

Is there anyone who can answer that question or does there exist another library for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You may try [CSSBox](http://cssbox.sourceforge.net). Just take a look at the *ComputeStyles* demo contained in the package (see the *doc/examples/README* file in the distribution package for information about running the demo). It computes all the styles and creates a new HTML document (represented by a DOM) with the corresponding inline style definitions.

The source is in *src/org/fit/cssbox/demo/ComputeStyles.java* and it's pretty short. Actually, it uses jStyleParser for doing the main job, CSSBox just provides a nicer interface for this.

```
        //Open the network connection 
        DocumentSource docSource = new DefaultDocumentSource(args[0]);

        //Parse the input document
        DOMSource parser = new DefaultDOMSource(docSource);
        Document doc = parser.parse();

        //Create the CSS analyzer
        DOMAnalyzer da = new DOMAnalyzer(doc, docSource.getURL());
        da.attributesToStyles(); //convert the HTML presentation attributes to inline styles
        da.addStyleSheet(null, CSSNorm.stdStyleSheet(), DOMAnalyzer.Origin.AGENT); //use the standard style sheet
        da.addStyleSheet(null, CSSNorm.userStyleSheet(), DOMAnalyzer.Origin.AGENT); //use the additional style sheet
        da.getStyleSheets(); //load the author style sheets

        //Compute the styles
        System.err.println("Computing style...");
        da.stylesToDomInherited();

        //Save the output
        PrintStream os = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(args[1]));
        Output out = new NormalOutput(doc);
        out.dumpTo(os);
        os.close();

        docSource.close();
```

Comment: Ack! It doesn't work in AppEngine! Curse you Google!

Comment: @radkovo How would this example be modified in case the source is a String input = "<html>...</html>" (instead of a URL)?  Nice work btw!

Comment: @athspk You would have to write your own DocumentSource implementation that creates an input stream from a string instead of an URL. This should be quite simple, just take a look at the original DefaultDocumentSource implementation. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247161/how-do-i-turn-a-string-into-a-stream-in-java) you may find how to create an input stream from a string.

Comment: Yes, in the end this is how i did it. Thanks again!

Comment: Can you create a example to create a DocumentSource from an html? I didnt find a way until now. I dont hava a file to read neither a file to output. I would like read a string and output a string...

Comment: At time of writing, CSSBox is not OSGI compliant. JSoup is an alternative, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4521557/automatically-convert-style-sheets-to-inline-style

Comment: Note the LGPL license for those looking to embed.

Answer (score 7):

I've been very happy with [JSoup](http://jsoup.org) (v1.5.2). I have a method like this:

```
 public static String inlineCss(String html) {
    final String style = "style";
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
    Elements els = doc.select(style);// to get all the style elements
    for (Element e : els) {
      String styleRules = e.getAllElements().get(0).data().replaceAll("\n", "").trim();
      String delims = "{}";
      StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(styleRules, delims);
      while (st.countTokens() > 1) {
        String selector = st.nextToken(), properties = st.nextToken();
        if (!selector.contains(":")) { // skip a:hover rules, etc.
          Elements selectedElements = doc.select(selector);
          for (Element selElem : selectedElements) {
            String oldProperties = selElem.attr(style);
            selElem.attr(style,
                oldProperties.length() > 0 ? concatenateProperties(
                    oldProperties, properties) : properties);
          }
        }
      }
      e.remove();
    }
    return doc.toString();
  }

  private static String concatenateProperties(String oldProp, @NotNull String newProp) {
    oldProp = oldProp.trim();
    if (!oldProp.endsWith(";"))
      oldProp += ";";
    return oldProp + newProp.replaceAll("\\s{2,}", " ");
  }
```

Comment: I think you are missing `concatenateProperties` function :)

Comment: Thanks @zozelfelfo - I added the missing function

Comment: Switching from mandrill to amazon ses - you saved my day :) 
Mandrill does this inlining by itself

Comment: @Nic Cottrell Not sure how this works for an external CSS document?

Comment: @JustinR you would just need to load the contents into the styleRules variable

Comment: I think this is still a great solution. But just a word of warning when using this with a CSS that uses some sort of inheritance, e.g. `* {color:blue}, p {color:red}` would make all your paragraphs `blue` _and_ `red`, leaving it to the browser, or maybe order of appearance, which one it will actually pick.