# Syntax highlight in android application (code browser)

Tags: java, android, android-webview, syntax-highlighting, textview

In an application that I'm developing my goal would be to have highlighted code for some language, i.e. Java, and make so that some elements of code (functions, parameters) are clickable.

I understood that I need some js-based syntax highlighter capable to output raw html instead of linking a CSS stylesheet to the code.

What I still don't get is:

1. Is there any highlighter that ouputs highlighted code in such format?
2. How to make just some words clickable?
3. Is there any alternative to this strategy?

**UPDATE1:** As first attempt, I downloaded the source code of the [android-codepad](http://code.google.com/p/android-codepad/) project, and edited the `HTMLViewerPlusPlus` class so that it highlights the HTML and, instead of showing it in a WebView, it shows it in a TextView, but since codepad uses css styling, I'm not getting the proper results. I'd need a new alternative that generates hard-styled html code.

**UPDATE2:** Using jsoup library with [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4521557/automatically-convert-style-sheets-to-inline-style) I managed to parse the code so that I get inline style attribute for each html element, but how to convert css styles to html tags?